# How to match nodes only by value? (not defining specific property)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to search nodes by value only, which can be in any of node properties. I know that this is an expensive operation, but nodes will be cut off by some relationship conditions.
I want something like this:

```
MATCH (n: {*:"Search value"})
RETURN n
```

Where * imply "any property".
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

interesting tidbits can be found in this abstract regarding this topic and why it might not be implemented

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FPfGkgzhcRXVkleBLBsA92U94Mx4yafu3nO-Xf-NzsE/edit#heading=h.pyvdg2rbofq

> Semantics of dynamic key expressions

Using a dynamic key expression like `<mapExpr>[<keyExpr>]` requires that `<mapExpr>` evaluates to a map or an entity, and that `<keyExpr>` evaluates to a string.  If this is not the case, a type error is produced either at compile time or at runtime.

If this is given, evaluating `<mapExpr>[<keyExpr>]` first evaluates `keyExpr` to a string value (the key), and then evaluates `<mapExpr>` to a map-like value (the map).  Finally the result of `<mapExpr>[<keyExpr>]` is computed by performing a lookup of the key in the map.  If the key is found, the associated value becomes the result. If the key is not found, `<mapExpr>[<keyExpr>]` evaluates to `NULL`.

Thus the result of evaluating `<mapExpr>[<keyExpr>]` can be any value (including `NULL`

> Caveats

Dynamic property lookup might entice users to encode information in property key names. This is bad practice as it interferes with planning, leads to unnatural data models, and might lead to exhausting the available property key id space.  This is addressed by issuing a warning when a query uses a dynamic property lookup with a dynamic property key name.

Comment: Could you please copy the most relevant part of the information at this link and paste here on stackoverflow? 

"Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." 

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, no. Seems to me that what you really are trying to do would be better achieved by creating a search index over the graph using something like elasticsearch or solr.  This would give you the ability to search over all properties. Your choice of analyzer whilst indexing would give you the option of exact or partial value matches.